# TFS Transition Set System.AssignedTo from a string field

Tags: tfs

I am modifying a workflow in TFS 2013 and have bumped into a snag.  Right now, when a developer completes their work and moves the work item into 'dev complete' I set the name of the developer moving the work item to a custom field as a string:

**MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy**

```
<FIELD name="Code Completed By" refname="MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy" type="String" reportable="dimension" syncnamechanges="true">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <HELPTEXT>The developer who wrote code related to this work item.</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

And here is the transition:

```
<TRANSITION from="Development in Progress" to="Code Review">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Ready for Code Review" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
      <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
    </FIELD>
    <FIELD refname="MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy">
      <DEFAULT from="currentuser" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

As the process continues the item eventually reaches QA.  IF the QA person finds a problem and rejects the work then I have a transition to move the work item back into the 'Development in Progress' state.  All of that works fine.

**The Problem**

I want to re-assign the work item, upon transition from QA in Progress back to Development in Progress, back to the original developer who did the work.

```
<TRANSITION from="QA in Progress" to="Development in Progress">
  <REASONS>
    <REASON value="Requirements Not Met" />
    <REASON value="Rejected" />
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Failed Testing" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
      <DEFAULT from="MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Unfortunately, when I attempt to apply my new WIT transitions it throws the following error:

```
TF212019: Work item tracking schema validation error at row 931, column 24: The 'from' attribute is invalid - The value 'MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2008/workitemtracking/typelib:CopyFrom' - The Enumeration constraint failed.
TF237070: Importing the definition failed. The definition you are trying to import did not validate against the schema. Edit the definition, then try to import it again.
```

I see that this is an Enumeration constraint issue, but I'm not familiar enough with TFS internal workings to know how to get around the problem.

Does anyone have a slick way of accomplishing what I am trying to do (even if I just need a completely new approach)?  I may just be going down the wrong path altogether.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the default which will simply try and set that as the value, try using the Copy rule.
Something like this:

```
<TRANSITION from="QA in Progress" to="Development in Progress">
  <REASONS>
    <REASON value="Requirements Not Met" />
    <REASON value="Rejected" />
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Failed Testing" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="System.AssignedTo">
      <COPY from="field" field="MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</TRANSITION>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the syntax like following:

```
<DEFAULT from="field" field="MYCOMPANY.Agile.Lean.CodeCompleteBy"/>
```

Refer to this link for details: [Define a default value or copy a value to a field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194948.aspx)